# Unexpected first EAP message in Diameter

Tags: java, diameter-protocol, aaa-security-protocol

So I've been looking at adding support for Diameter EAP in my server. After reading up on `rfc4072` and `rfc3748` I was fooled to have a general idea.

My expectation was that the client would pass a so called `EAP-Start` message (an empty `EAP-Payload` AVP) to my server. I would respond with an proper EAP request for identity (type 1) and diameter client would deliver the response to that in the new EAP-Payload and then the cycle would continue.

However, when I was looking at actual pcap traces from `freeDiameter` (ex [this pcap](http://lists.freediameter.net/pipermail/help/attachments/20120913/2b85ef2a/attachment-0001.obj)) I noticed that the 1st EAP diameter request (No.6) contained an EAP Identity response (!!) already. Kind of by-passing the initial round-trip.

While I don't have a huge a problem with implementing this I would really like to know if this is by (EAP-)spec? Can you start an EAP transaction with a response with?

Comment: From `rfc3748`: "An authenticator receiving a´Response whose Identifier value does not match that of the currently outstanding Request MUST silently discard the Response.". This makes me think that this pcap is violating the spec.

Comment: rfc4072 (EAP over Diameter) mentions this behaviour in chapter 2.2 (Protocol Overview): "A preferred approach is for the access device to issue the EAP-Request/Identity message to the EAP client, and forward the EAP-Response/Identity packet, encapsulated within the EAP-Payload AVP, as a Diameter-EAP-Request to the Diameter server".

Comment: You got it right: ONLY server shluld send EAP-start, so client MUST start with EAP-response. Server should ignore non-existing EAP connections and respond with EAP-Start for ANY_ID_REQ or similar, so client can response again with EAP-response (basically sending the same EAP message twice)

Answer (score 0):

Yes - actually, that IS in the spec.

```
   EAP authentication is initiated by the server (authenticator),
   whereas many authentication protocols are initiated by the client
   (peer).  As a result, it may be necessary for an authentication
   algorithm to add one or two additional messages (at most one
   roundtrip) in order to run over EAP.
```

So you need ANY message to trigger the server to start EAP sequence. That is why usually you see the same message twice.